# change icon on menu link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

On my menu I have a font awesome icon that I would like to be able to change once click on parent link.

I am trying to get it if menu link is closed will show

And if menu link is open will show

Currently my java script not working.

I can only get it to change if change it manually but trying to get java script to do so.

```
<?php echo Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');?>
<div id="wrapper">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">

</nav>

<div class="menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu">
        <li>
            <a class="parent" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#setting"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> System <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
            <ul id="setting" class="collapse">
                <li class="third-level">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> First Level</a>
                    <ul id="user" class="collapse">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Second Level</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> Dashboard <small>Dashboard Home</small></h1>
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.parent').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
$(".parent").addClass('fa fa-angle-right').removeClass('fa fa-angle-down');
});
</script>
<?php echo Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the listener to the object that is actually collapsing:

```
$('#setting').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(".parent").addClass('fa fa-angle-right').removeClass('fa-angle-down');
});
```

`#setting` is the element being collapsed, so the event happens there.

Comment: did not work tried that I had removed the hard coded manual icon that I put in and nothing showed up.

Comment: seems to work ok in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wonoretuziji/1/edit), maybe the fa class is on the wrong element?

Comment: Got it working was one of my other js was having effect on it

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong here is you jquery syntax

`$('.parent').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {});`

The correct syntax looks like `$('.parent <sub classes>').on('click', function() {});`

Comment: this is a [bootstrap event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage) for collapse not a list of classes, so the syntax is actually correct